# Applying a CIFilter to an image produces empty UIImage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-image, cifilter

I’m trying to apply a CIFilter to an image that I receive from `UIImagePickerController`. Here is the code I’m using:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UIImage *userImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    UIImage *croppedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(userImage.CGImage, CGRectMake(0, 320, 640, 640))];

    CIContext *context = [CIContext contextWithOptions:nil];
    CIImage *img = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage.CGImage];
    CIFilter *adjustFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CILineOverlay"];

    [adjustFilter setDefaults];
    [adjustFilter setValue:img forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [adjustFilter setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0] forKey:@"inputNRSharpness"];
    CIImage *adjustedImage = [adjustFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey];
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCIImage:[context createCGImage:adjustedImage fromRect:adjustedImage.extent]];

    NSLog(@"%@", newImage);

    self.myImageView.image = newImage;

}
```

Now, when the process of applying the filter is done (there are no errors popping up), no image is visible in the image view (though the console does log `<UIImage: 0x8b91810>`). If I skip the processing part and just assign the unfiltered `croppedImage` to the image view, it is displayed fine.

So what am I doing wrong here? I’m wanting to use this code to process a screenshot, but I’ve tried it with a photo and got the same (zero) result.

Comment: [CILineOverlay Filter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CILineOverlay) is not available in iOS yet.

Comment: There is a open source library for this ["GPUImage Framework"](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage#visual-effects), kindly try these 3 filters it may help you!
1) GPUImageCrosshatchFilter
2) GPUImageSketchFilter
3) GPUImageToonFilter